# Laravel 5.2 How I Can Update Form in Condition The Files Forms is Blank?

Tags: php, forms, function, laravel, laravel-5

Hy again. I'm trying to updated my form, with multiple upload. It's work. But, whenever I tried to blank the files form, it's always appear:

> ErrorException in ProductController.php line 160: Undefined offset: 0

Okay, now I have two(or three) options:

1. Makes the forms and multiple upload separated, so the controller function is also separated.
2. Edited my code, but I don't know where I supposed to edit.
3. Suggest me, anything would be help.

Here's my code (work well, unless if I'm not fill the files form):

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $update = $request->all();
    //dd($update);
    $product = Product::find($id);

    $picture = ''; 
    $images = [];
    if ($request->hasFile('images')) {
      $files = $request->file('images');
      //dd($files);

    foreach($files as $file){
        if (isset($file)){
        $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $picture = date('His').$filename;
        $destinationPath = base_path() . '\public\images/';
        $file->move($destinationPath, $picture);
        array_push($images, $picture);
    }
    }
    //dd($update);
    //dd($images);
    }

     if (!empty($update['images']) && isset($images)) {
        $update['images'] = $images[0];
        $update['images2'] = $images[1];
        $update['images3'] = $images[2];
        $update['images4'] = $images[3];
        } else {
        unset($product['images'] -> $images);
        }
    //dd($update);
    $product->update($update); 
    return redirect('product');
}
```

And the form:

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('Images', 'Images:') !!}
    {!! Form::file('images[]',null,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
</div>
```

Thank you, have a nice day!

Comment: If you're confused about the question (sorry I'm bad when explain something hehe), the main questions is: How I can update without fill the files form, and without update the images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that when your `images` array is empty you can't access the `[0]` index. However, this is compounded by the fact that your conditional is always true. The conditional statement you've used is insufficient here:

```
isset($images);
```

This is because previously you `declared` images.

```
$images = [];
```

So instead what you want is to check the `count` of the images array. We can do that like this:

```
count($images) > 0
```

So the final conditional would be:

```
if (!empty($update['images']) && count($images) > 0) {
```

Comment: I copied the conditional but it showed error `Indirect modification of overloaded element of App\Product has no effect`.

Comment: I edited the `$images = [];`  to `$images = array(0, 1, 2, 3);` and trying your code too, it's work now. Thank you!

Comment: I mean $images = array(0, 1, 2, 3)